# Get Leaf Property Value Out Of Object's Tree Graph

Tags: c#

I am stuck with PropertyInfo, big time. Basically it a tiny issue though idk where to start solving it. I dont usually use reflection but I need it now.

I have an object which has a property of type MyClass and MyClass futhermore holds another property. I want that last one. How do I get it?

Take a look at this:

```
obj.myClass.Attribute
```

How do I get that Attribute property by using PropertyInfo?

Comment: Use a recursive function. The question isn't really "how to get a propery's property" but "how do I walk an object graph?"

Comment: pseudo; typeof(obj.myClass).getProperty("Attribute")

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I would know how to walk an object graph I wouldnt be asking this question would I? Hehehe. Please enlighten me. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PropertyInfo.GetValue(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx):

```
Type         type  = obj.myClass.GetType();
PropertyInfo prop  = type.GetProperty("Attribute");
object       value = prop.GetValue(obj.myClass);
```